# How to apply paging in Django's formview?

Tags: django, pagination, formview

my view.py

```
class Formtestview(FormView): 
    template_name = 'test.html'
    form_valid(self, form): 
           'my code to search' => 'result is object_list'
            page = self.request.GET.get('page','1')
            paginate = Paginator(object_list, 10)
            page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)
            return render(self.request, 'test.html', {'form':self.form_class, 'object_list':object_list, 'page_obj' = page_obj})
```

As in the code above, input is received through form_valid, paged, and then sprayed on the same html template.

Results and paging are also displayed normally, but if you go to another page like ?page=2, only the basic template without all the results is shown.

Is there a way to paginate the form and search results in one template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you use `FormView`? Pagination comes with [MultipleObjectMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginate_by). For simplicity, you can use `ListView` rather than `FormView`. ListView is inherited from `MultipleObjectMixin`.

This example is from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview):

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

from myapp.models import Contact

class ContactListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 2
    model = Contact
```

Comment: I display the form for the first time and use the key to be submitted for the form and display the result right at the bottom.

When I use listview the form is displayed but submit doesn't work

What's the problem ?